# Copy an array of sheets using a variable Sheets(Array(Variable)).Copy

Tags: arrays, variables, copy

I'm having real trouble creating a string to use as the variable to copy differing tabs each time it's run depending on which cells are ticked.

My code cycles through a row of cells and anything with a tick (P) then adds to the array string.
The text generated in the string is identical to the hard coded equivalent but I get a runtime error 9 when I try to copy the tabs using the string.
The "rw" is populated in a previous macro that call this one.

My code is

```
public rw, col  as long
public add      as string
public add1     as variable

sub create_pack

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    col1 = 8
    add = ""
    Do Until col1 > 17
        If sh00.Cells(rw, col1) = "P" Then
            If add = "" Then
                add = """Pack " & col1 - 7 & """"
            Else
                add = add & ", ""Pack " & col1 - 7 & """"
            End If
        End If
        col1 = col1 + 1
    Loop

    add1 = Array(add)
    wb1.Sheets(add1).Copy
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
```

[image]

Any help gratefully received as I'm completely stumped on this one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by copying tab by tab.
Hope this helps any subsequent viewers.

```
Sub create_pack()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

col = 8

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.add
wb1.Activate

Do Until col > 17
    If sh00.Cells(rw, col) = "P" Then wb1.Sheets("Pack " & col - 7).Copy After:=wb2.Sheets(wb2.Sheets.Count)
    col = col + 1
Loop

wb2.Activate
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete    
wb2.Close False

wb1.Activate
```

End Sub